# Is it possible to virtualize war file execution without separate J2EE container deployments?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, websphere, weblogic, jetty

Let's say I want to allow my developers to upload their `war` files to a web app (*not the application server itself*) running on our intranet and **that web app** would then *run* those wars **as if they were separate apps deployed individually in our J2EE container**.

In other words, we are not actually deploying the `wars` as separate apps in the container - they are simply running side-by-side *inside this one web app* **that acts like a J2EE container**.

Is that possible?

Something like a `war` virtualization app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start creating `ClassLoader`, expanding the `.war`, loading the classes and dispatching the request to your application to the right sub web app. That looks like re-inventing the wheel (given that the app. server does that already) and is probably very complicated.

On the other side, this looks terribly similar to how `portlets` work. Portlets are packaged into a `.war` file and are then used by the portal. For instance, in Liferay portal, you can upload a portlet `.war` from the liferay portal (not the app. server itself). Liferay will then place the uploaded `.war` file in the auto-deploy directory of the app. server which will then be deployed like a regular web app. Then there is the portlet bridge that dispatch the request from the portal to the right portlet web app, etc. It's maybe worth having a closer look at that.

I don't know your requirements, but I would definitively try do keep it simple as such stuff can get really complicated. But you could:

- Let user upload the `.war` from you application
- Manipulate the `.war` and `web.xml` to ensure that the context is something like `/ParentApp/ChildApp`
- Save the modified `.war` to the auto-deploy folder and let the app. server deploy it

This will provide the illusion the you can deploy sub webapp from your parent webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason why you need them to run side the context of another war? Sounds like what you need to do to achieve your goal - it's probably impossible to do if you're running it inside your war - is to build a war which then takes that war they upload and uses the API for deploying wars that the web server exposes to deploy the war and thus let it run as a top level web app. I don't think there's any other way to do it.